# How to scale a program for reversing a String?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, scalability, divide-and-conquer

I have the following algorithm for reversing a string:

1. Create two pointers head and tail.
2. Head points to the first element of the string and tail points to the last element.
3. Increment head and decrement tail, till head is less than tail and swap elements pointed by head and tail while doing so.

Sounds good! It's an O(n) algorithm.

Now how will I make this algorithm scalable? Suppose I want to reverse a 50,000-pages book and I want to swap the last character in the book present on last page with the first character on first page in the book, second last with second and so on..... What should be the approach here? Can we use divide and conquer strategy/ Hadoop Map Reduce?

Comment: just read it backwards

Comment: it sounds like you have not tried anything and just ask us to parallelize your algorithm...

Comment: Thats why I asked the approach and not the solution.

Comment: Split 50000 pages into chunks, reverse individually and then concatenate results together in reverse order.